# pthread_create fails w/ ENOMEM?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am seeing pthread_create() fail with rc=12 (ENOMEM), on a 64-bit RHEL machine with 4GB of real memory. The 'top' command shows the process is using 1G of virtual memory when thread creation fails.

I am able to create 16 joinable threads, but the 17th and subsequent calls fail with the ENOMEM error (which apparently means memory -or- some other resource is unavailable). Any thoughts on what's going wrong?

Comment: Really hard to say.  It should be able to create more threads than that, especially on a 64-bit machine (is your program compiled with 64-bit pointers, though?) where address space fragmentation should be a non-issue.  Could you strace -f the program and post an excerpt (a couple dozen lines before and after the system call, whatever it was, that actually returned ENOMEM should suffice), please?

Comment: Could be stack size. Are you explicitly setting it when you create the threads?

Comment: No, I am using the default stack size (ulimit -s says 10240k)
`code`
pthread_attr_t  threadAttr;
pthread_t       threadID;
pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&threadAttr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
pthread_attr_setscope(&threadAttr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
int rc = pthread_create(&threadID, &threadAttr,
                         (void*(*)(void*))myTask, myParms);
`code`

Comment: pl. add your code & strace as requested by @Zack as an edit in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the program under strace and saw the following:

```
mmap(NULL, 10489856, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|0x40, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
mmap(NULL, 10489856, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
```

**UPDATE:**  Don't ask me why, but the following change fixes the issue:

```
pthread_attr_setscope(pattr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this](http://www.parkes.atnf.csiro.au/observing/documentation/computing_notes/linux_threads.html). Seems to be a system limitation, but I'm not completely sure. However, that site provides a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

pthread_create() can fail if the available virtual memory in the process is fragmented: there is not enough space (no "hole" sufficiently large) to allocate the thread's stack as described [here](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/problem_of_thread_creation.html).